# Line delimiter or separator in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

In eclipse there is an option in Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> New text file line delimiter. This options is for which type of line separator to be used like windows (\n), unix (\n\r) or mac.

I checked the pycharm settings but didn't find the particular option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option is "Line separators" and present in File of pycharm. I have attached a screenshot

[image]

Comment: This is for **current** file. For **new files** (similar to Eclipse) it should be under `Settings | Code Style | General`

Comment: In PyCharm 4.0.5 it is under `File > Settings... > Editor > Code Style > (on the right) Line separator (for new files)`